# Objective-c Refactoring, where does the code belong?

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, refactoring

I'm working on a iOS client for a web-service, I get data from a Json API which I parse and saves into CoreData. I have some duplication, mainly with how I parse and save objects. One example is a method for creating users which is almost identical in two controllers (would probably be more in the future):

```
- (User *)createUserFromDict:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{

    User *user;

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter= [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber * userId = [numberFormatter numberFromString:(NSString *)[dictionary valueForKey:@"id"]];
    NSEntityDescription *userDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:[appController managedObjectContext]];
    NSEntityDescription *imageDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext:[appController managedObjectContext]];

    user = [[User alloc] initWithEntity:userDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[appController managedObjectContext]];
    user.name = [dictionary valueForKey:@"name"];
    [...]

    Image *userAvatrar = [[Image alloc] initWithEntity:imageDescription    insertIntoManagedObjectContext:[appController managedObjectContext]];
    userAvatrar.url = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"avatar_image.url"];
    [...]
    NSError *error;
    [[appController managedObjectContext] save:&error];

    return user;
}
```

I'm not sure if this duplication is nesecary, or if there is a better way to do it. I'm thinking of creating a "cacheManager" controller class and store methods like this here, or put it in my models. Which would be the best/correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to make it a class method of your User object:

```
+ (User *)insertUserFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary inManagedObjectContext: (NSManagedObjectContext*) moc
{

    User *user = nil;

    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter= [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    NSNumber * userId = [numberFormatter numberFromString:(NSString *)[dictionary valueForKey:@"id"]];
       NSEntityDescription *userDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext: moc];
    NSEntityDescription *imageDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Image" inManagedObjectContext: moc];

    user = [[User alloc] initWithEntity:userDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:moc];
    user.name = [dictionary valueForKey:@"name"];
    [...]

    Image *userAvatrar = [[Image alloc] initWithEntity:imageDescription    insertIntoManagedObjectContext: moc];
    userAvatrar.url = [dictionary valueForKeyPath:@"avatar_image.url"];
    [...]
    NSError *error;
    [moc save:&error];

    return user;
}
```

You of course call it like this:

```
User *newUser = [User insertUserFromDictionary: userDictionary inManagedObjectContext: appcontroller.managedObjectContext];
```

Consider also moving the context's save operation out of this class method and invoke it "yourself" after the user has been inserted, which I haven't done here.

Comment: What about putting this inside a category?

Comment: Class methods are generally under used but provide a benefit of clearly indicating there are no instance variable side-effects.

Comment: @KevinM Categories are not usually a good choice. These days creating a class does not require much boilerplate.

Comment: I was assuming the OP had access to the User class (which I guess he does), so I proposed a class method. A category would be a choice, if the OP wasn't able to modify the User class.

Answer (score 3):

DRY - The Don't Repeat Yourself principle not only saves code but more importantly allows for maintenance in one place instead of several.

The Single Responsibility principle states that each unit (class/method) should only do one thing.

Thus eliminate the duplicated code.

Wether a class or method depends on how involved the caching is and future needs. You can go slow with a method and refactor later into a class if that makes sense.

If the two controllers that use it are separate classes it seems that a new class is probably the way to proceed.

That will also make the code easier to follow given good naming conventions.